# INSERT from SELECT statement, column count

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, sql-insert

Table1 has one column and table2 has three columns. The names are all unique.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name = 'Brian')
```

#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

What is the easiest way to append NULL or empty strings to the results of the SELECT query?

I have tried this and many other variations:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = 'Brian', '','') 
INSERT INTO test2 ((SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = 'Brian') + '' , '')
```

Comment: Stop using `SELECT *` and list the columns, and use NULL (not `''`) where NULL is needed, as in `SELECT Col1, Col2, NULL, Col4 FROM ...`. Or, list the columns in your INSERT INTO, as in `INSERT INTO table2 (Col1, Col2, Col4, Col5) (SELECT Col1, Col2, Col4, Col5 FROM ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to specify the column names in both source and target tables:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col2) -- change col2 to the name of the column in table2 that will receive the values
SELECT col1 -- change col1 to the name of the column in table1
FROM table1 
WHERE name = 'Brian';
```

All other than `col2` columns in `table2` will be set to `null` or their default values (if defined in the table's definition).

Even if `col1` is the only column in `table1`, you should prefer `SELECT col1` over `SELECT *`, because if you add any columns to the table `SELECT *` would stop working.